# How to use GetNamedSecurityInfo?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get my computer shared folder's permission information. But I don't know that use `GetNamedSecurityInfo` function. Is it right to use the function to get the permission information?

This is my code:

```
TCHAR *path= _T("E:\\down\\test.txt");
PACL dacl = NULL;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psd = NULL;
DWORD result = 0;

try
{
    result = GetNamedSecurityInfo( path,
        SE_FILE_OBJECT,
        DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &dacl,
        NULL,
        &psd );     

}catch(DWORD e)
{
    //error
}

LocalFree( psd );
```

Comment: A Win32 function is unlikely to throw a c++ exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to pass pointers to variables instead of all those NULLs you passed to the function because that is where you will get the security information in, please read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645(v=vs.85).aspx